# Cleaning a CSV of multiple CSVs joined together and putting into a common CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas, header, dataframe

I want to use pandas/python.

I have multiple CSVs that have common column names but different orders those columns appear.

They have been combined into one CSV, all headers of each CSV preserved.

Example headers are:

- title, description, joblocation
- ...., ... , ...
- joblocation, hiringorganization, industry, title
- ... , ..., ..., ...
- description, dateposted, joblocation, industry
- ..., .... ,....

How do I:

1. Loop through each row from the header till the start of the next CSV
2. Look up the cell in each row to the column header it is part of, and move all the cells in that column to the correct 'master schema'
3. Move onto the next CSV section and do the same, putting each cell underneath the right column header in the process.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far, and what it's doing?

Comment: You can use `csv.DictReader` in python. So you get `{'col1':'val1`...}` style.By this way you can find which value represents which column.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that you have already gone through the trouble of combining your csv files into one master file, but there might be a better way.

If you were construct a list of data frames and each of those data frames represented one of csv files you could leverage pandas' concat.  A very useful function for combining multiple frames with common headers into one frame

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html